# data porting from one system to another in r

Tags: r, data-transfer-objects

how do you port R objects from one system to another? I presume this is a very simple question(pardon my naivete), but I couldn't find any answer on the Internet.

Very many thanks for your time and effort....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save all objects using :

```
save.image(file='myEnvironment.RData')
```

you can also specify what you want to save with :

```
save(db,file = 'mydb.RData')
```

and to load it, use :

```
load(file)
```